# css background color not working with <div>

Tags: html, css, background-color

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFDEC;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #04A7A6;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}

.headermenu {
    xposition: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

This code => doesn't display my second header...? I know it has something to do with the header conflicting with the headermenu, but it doesn't conflict with the body background?

Comment: Change `xposition:fixed;` to `position:fixed;`, `<.h1>BAM</h1>` to `<h1>BAM</h1>`

Comment: `xposition` that is one nice attribute I wish it actually existed :)

Answer (score 4):

should

```
xposition:fixed;
```

be

```
position:fixed;
```

?

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/nv8as/)